# Auto increment are not showing in select list when error occurred inserting duplicate values in unique key

Tags: sql

I m creating a table with 1 identity column and 1 unique column.But when we insert a duplicate values in table then it show error as we are expected,But identity column incremented by 1.which is not showing.Our Question is Why Identity column increase?
Example :-

```
create table test (
id int identity( 1,1) ,
name varchar(20) not null unique,
description varchar(100)
)
```

First insert command :-

```
insert into test
values(‘Hello’,’India’)
```

again run same command

```
insert into test
values(‘Hello’,’India’)
```

error which is expected

**Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint ‘UQ__test__72E12F1B1571C0B7′. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ‘dbo.test’. The duplicate key value is (Hello).
The statement has been terminated.**

```
insert into test
values(‘Hello Kalyan’,’India’)
```

then ouput is

```
id  name     description
1   Hello        India
3   Hello Kalyan India
```

why 2 is missing in table?

Please Help.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the SQL comman Get Scope Identity

```
insert into test
values(SELECT( SCOPE_IDENTITY),‘Hello’,’India’)
```

Scope identity gets the next unique key value.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.  Hence the downvote.

Comment: @DanBracuk wow your right, oh well good example. your right what an odd question. However my answer solves the problem..